# C++ different using declarations for different concepts

Tags: c++, optimization, c++20, micro-optimization, c++-concepts

Let's say, I have my `List<T>` class. I have a lot of functions where I have to pass a single object of my `T` type. For instance

```cpp
void add(const T& item)
{
    ...
}
```

and it makes sense if `T` is some class or a struct. However, if `T` is a byte or integer, it's pointless or even wrong to pas it via reference, since memory pointer costs 8 bytes (4 on 32 bit system), i.e. I pass 1 byte size data type via 8 byte size pointer.

And so I decided to define argument data type using `using` directive. Kind of:

```cpp
using argType = const T&; requires sizeof(T) > 8
using argType = T; requires sizeof(T) <= 8
```

But, obviously, this code doesn't work. Can you, please, propose me other solutions for that?

Comment: I think you may see c++20 concepts for adding constraints to your templates: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: Yes, but how can I apply it to my problem? Other than duplication each function for both cases. This is my question.

Comment: You might consider [Boost Call Traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm). You might also consider adding move support for the types that benefit from that, which won't happen if they're all const references.

Comment: Does it show up as a performance regression in any tests you have conducted?

Comment: @TanveerBadar not much (I mean, regression is really low). However, if you're interested, there is my test code with conclusions: https://pastebin.com/EC7szuJ9

Comment: Do you guys actually see performance boosts with these types of optimizations? I lean heavily on profiler and I never noticed a case where replacing const T& with T results in any improvement (and I have tried). It seems to me like optimizing compilers are smart enough to know that if `sizeof(T)<N` (N might be, say, 64 bytes) and T is trivially-copyable that there is no need involve a level of pointer indirection to pass it by const reference. They optimize away the indirection well enough in my experience, and this seems to have been true enough even in the early 2000s.

Comment: Unless there are cases shown where this is beneficial, I think such attempts at optimization are needlessly skyrocketing build times making the compiler jump through hoops only to perform an optimization it could already perform without doing so. I hope my tone doesn't come across as challenging though. I'm genuinely curious since I would be happy to add such optimizations to my arsenal of tools. But they have been futile in my experience.

Comment: @Espeon I just noticed yours but it's difficult for me to draw it as conclusive. There are heap allocations involved that make order matter, things of this sort. I'd be interested in what an assembly expert would make of the disassembly of both versions. I did tinker with the exact same idea long ago and didn't find it beneficial at all let alone enough in production. I have noticed plenty of cases where doing counter-intuitive things that I thought the optimizer would optimize away resulted in performance boosts across multiple compilers/platforms (jump tables/__asume, e.g.), but not this.

Comment: @DrunkRider it may be so because I have good CPU in my gaming PC and I never tried to limit it. The difference may be more noticeable on older/weaker CPUs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is [`conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
class List {
  using argType = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(T) > 8), const T&, T>;
  
  void add(argType item) { }
};
```

Comment: Yes, it actually seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Note that objects with sizeof==8 but with expensive copy constructors will be pass by value. See my answer for the problem and solution.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69864339/2963099 where `conditional_t` was suggested

It is important to make sure that items with non-trivial copy constructors are passed by reference, since a value copy can be very expensive. As such I would limit pass by value to trivially copyable objects.

Also using `sizeof(T*)` will work more generically than a hardcoded `8`

Note that args are reversed and the test is to use pass by value, and objects with sizeof == 8 can still be pass by reference if needed.

```cpp
using argType = std::conditional_t<
    (sizeof(T) <= sizeof(T *)) && std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>,
    T, const T&>;
```

An example of usage:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    Test() : x{0}
    {
        std::cout << "Default construct" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test(const Test& rhs) : x{rhs.x}
    {
        std::cout << "copy: " << x << std::endl;
    }
    int * x;
};

template<class T>
struct List {
  using argType = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(T *)) && std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>, T, const T&>;
  
  static argType copy(argType item)
    { 
        std::cout << "Running Copy" << std::endl;
        return item;
    }
};

auto foo(typename List<Test>::argType t)
{
    return List<Test>::copy(t);
}

auto goo(typename List<unsigned long long>::argType t)
{
    return List<unsigned long long>::copy(t);
}

int main()
{
    Test t;
    std::cout << "Calling Test Copy" << std::endl;
    foo(t);
    std::cout << "After Test Copy" << std::endl;

    unsigned long long u;
    std::cout << "Calling ULL Copy" << std::endl;
    goo(u);
    std::cout << "After ULL Copy" << std::endl;
}
```

see it here: https://godbolt.org/z/WTKT8G6rh
Note, you can see the parameter of foo() and goo() easily here

Note how Test would have been passed by value and incurred a possibly expensive copy, but checking for an expensive copy prevents this

Comment: Actually, yes. A very good comment about comparing to actual pointer size instead of 8

Comment: And thanks for std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>, I can use it for optimizing my vector memory rearrangement, i.e. use memcpy on trivial array memory block

Answer (score 0):

With c++20 concepts you can add some constraints to your templates,

from [en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)

> Class templates, function templates, and non-template functions (typically members of class templates) may be associated with a constraint, which specifies the requirements on template arguments, which can be used to select the most appropriate function overloads and template specializations.
> Named sets of such requirements are called concepts. Each concept is a predicate, evaluated at compile time, and becomes a part of the interface of a template where it is used as a constraint:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <concepts>
 
// Declaration of the concept "Hashable", which is satisfied by any type 'T'
// such that for values 'a' of type 'T', the expression std::hash<T>{}(a)
// compiles and its result is convertible to std::size_t
template<typename T>
concept Hashable = requires(T a) {
    { std::hash<T>{}(a) } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};
 
struct meow {};
 
// Constrained C++20 function template:
template<Hashable T>
void f(T) {}
//
// Alternative ways to apply the same constraint:
// template<typename T>
//    requires Hashable<T>
// void f(T) {}
//
// template<typename T>
// void f(T) requires Hashable<T> {}
 
int main() {
  using std::operator""s;
  f("abc"s); // OK, std::string satisfies Hashable
//f(meow{}); // Error: meow does not satisfy Hashable
}
```

In your case I think you can constraint your template as follows:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept InfTo8Bytes = requires(T a) {
  sizeof (T) <= 8;
};
```

and use you concepts as follows:

```
template<InfTo8Bytes T>
class Foo {

};
```

Comment: As in the comment, this doesn't prevent duplicating the function, one with the constraint and one without.

Comment: As I understand, I will not be able to use it for types that are not numbers. Or I will have to create a copy without restriction.